# How to connect a ListView that's not in the main layout?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, listview

I am working on my first rather big project in android studio and I've been struggling for the past three days with this:

My app has a bottom navigation component that opens 3 other fragments and I was wondering how I could implement a ListView into one of those 3 fragments. I managed to put the ListView in the main layout (activity_main.xml), but as soon as I put the ListView into a layout that's not the main layout I get an NPE. I guess that's because if I try to link the ListView to its data with findViewById(R.id.ListView) it's looking for ListView in activity_main. The code that tries to link the ListView to the component in the layout-file is written in the onCreate in the mainActivity.java. How can I tell the programm to look for the ListView in layout_With_List.xml?

I read on another question that I need to change the setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) in onCreate to setContentView(R.layout.layout_With_List), but that just creates another error.

So how can I properly put a ListView into another fragment, so it won't float around in the main layout when I change tabs with the bottom navigation AND make it display data?

The error i'm getting:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

This is the Relevant code bits:

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv_productlist = findViewById(R.id.lv_productlist);

    showFoodOnListView(db_helper);
}
```

The code that passes data to the ListView:

```
    private void showFoodOnListView(DB_Helper db_helper2) {
    food_ArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Product_Model>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, db_helper2.getEveryone());
    lv_productlist.setAdapter(food_ArrayAdapter);
}
```

layout_With_List.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/lv_productlist"
    android:name="com.ocdm.prepper.ListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context=".ListFragment"
    tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_list" />
```

===========================SOLUTION===============================

Thanks to [https://stackoverflow.com/users/4039784/hayssam-soussi]

I could figure it out.

```
        lv_productlist = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.R.id.lv_productlist);

        showFoodOnListView(db_helper);
```

I had to move the code above into the Layouts corresponding java class, e.g fragment_A.java.

Then I had to move the method showFoodOnListView into fragment_A.java
and set the context to `getActivity():`.

```
food_ArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Product_Model>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, db_helper2.getEveryone());
```

Comment: Include the listview in the fragment's layout and access it from that fragment NOT the main activity

Comment: One more thing to notice is that your ListView is actually a RecyclerView

Comment: @PrinceAli I know about the recyclerview, that was a temporary experiment. Could you ellaborate on how I should go about accessing it from that fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you need to add the ListView to **Fragment A**

First you have to create a layout for Fragment A (i.e fragment_a.xml)

Add your `ListView` to fragment_a.xml

Then your `FragmentA.java` code should look like this:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        // get the reference of ListView
        lv_productlist = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_productlist);

        showFoodOnListView(db_helper);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would need to bring the showFoodOnListView method into FragmentA.java too, wouldn't I?

Comment: Yes move it inside the FragmentA.java code

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed. The only thing that "bugged" me out was which context to give foodArrayAdapter but I figured it out, it was .getActivity()

Comment: I marked it as the solution and upvoted. But my reputation is below 15, so it doesn't get shown. Anyway thanks again for your help. I was stuck for so long!